# selecting data using mysql join query

Tags: mysql

this query works.

TABLE users

```
userid   firstname    lastname
1         JOHN         DEO
2         JANE         DEO

TABLE msg

msg_id    msg_from     msg_to      received   
1         userid(1)    userid(2)   null       


SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
  ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid -1'
  AND M.received IS NULL
```

but this query doesn't work

```
TABLE users

userid   firstname    lastname
1         JOHN         DEO
2         JANE         DEO

TABLE msg

msg_id    msg_from     msg_to      received   age  city  country
1         userid(1)    userid(2)   null       26   any   any


SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, SND.age, SND.city, SND.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
  ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid -1'
  AND M.received IS NULL
```

i want to select age city country from database on table msg but looks my query has problem the one which to select age city and country from table msg

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `SND.age,SND.city,SND.country` to `M.age,M.city,M.country` since they are from table `msg`

```
SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, M.age, M.city, M.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
  ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid -1'
  AND M.received IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query:

```
SELECT SND.userid, SND.firstname, SND.lastname, M.age, M.city, M.country
FROM msg as M
JOIN users as SND 
ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE M.msg_to = 'userid -1'
AND M.received IS NULL
```

Comment: Welcome.. :-) .